# Text input for adding an ignored tag turns white when loading the tags in dark mode

Tags: bug, dark-mode

When adding an ignored tag, the text input’s background turns white when the tags are being loaded in dark mode:

[image: GIF of the background of the text input when adding an ignored tag turning white in dark mode]

This seems to be due to the CSS of the `ac_loading` class:

```css
.ac_loading {
  background: #fff url(../../Img/progress-dots.gif?v=679ddd617b7d) right center no-repeat
}
```

I created a userscript to fix this:

```js
const style = document.createElement('style')
style.textContent = `
  .ac_loading {
    background-color: var(--white);
  }
`
document.head.append(style)
```